# How to get correct xpath

Tags: xpath, automated-tests

I was learning xpath and want to ask everybody about this following:

```
//div[@id="DupontDiv"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]
```

Use this xpath ==> when running system, It get both numbers and combine them ==> 44.7813.02%

```
//div[@id="DupontDiv"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/text()
```

Use this xpath ==> can search (by yellow color) but when running system return empty

Can you help to show me xpath to get 44.78 only

or (split two numbers by a space ==> 44.78  13.02%)

[image]

Comment: You already have a unique entry in HTMLDOM, what is the issue ?

Comment: //div[@id="DupontDiv"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]  ==> this xpath combine two number 44.7813.02%  ==> how can I split them or get only one 44.78 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to get the total text of that `td` element and then to remove from it the text contained in `span` element.
I assume you are using Selenium with Python. If so you can do the following:

```py
total_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id="DupontDiv"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]").text
child_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id="DupontDiv"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]//span").text
parent_only_text = total_text.replace(child_text, '')
```